# getting two data separated by space and calculate in java

Tags: java, get, set, java.util.scanner, whitespace

My problem is I want to input two numbers separated by a space and getting those two numbers and compute those two numbers. for example, i typed "10 20", they are separated by a space and then I want to get and compute them as separate: 10 * 20 = 200..

what I have is a getter and setter for this part
these are my code:

MY GETTER AND SETTER CLASS

```
import java.util.*;

public class LabExer2
{
    private String itemName;
    private double itemPrice;
    private int itemQuantity;
    private double amountDue;

    public void setItemName(String newItemName)
    {
        itemName = newItemName;
    }

    public String getItemName()
    {
        return itemName;
    }

    public void setTotalCost(int quantity, double price)
    {
        itemQuantity = quantity;
        itemPrice = price;

        amountDue = itemQuantity * itemPrice;
    }

    public double getTotalCost()
    {
        return amountDue;
    }

    public void readInput()
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the name of the item you are purchasing.");
        itemName = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the quantity and price separated by a space.");
        //itemQuantity = s.nextInt();
        //itemPrice = s.nextDouble();

    }

    public void writeInput()
    {
        System.out.println("You are purchasing " + itemQuantity + " " + itemName + "(s) at " + itemPrice + " each.");
        System.out.println("Amount due is " + getTotalCost());
    }
}
```

MY MAIN CLASS

```
public class MainLabExer2
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        LabExer2 le = new LabExer2();
        //still not finished because I can't figure out the process in the other class.
    }
}
```

The output I wanted to have:

Enter the name of the item you are purchasing.
pencil
Enter the quantity and price separated by a space.
3 15.50
You are purchasing 3 pencil(s) at 15.50 each.
Amount due is 46.50

I want to get the 3 and 15.50 and compute. I don't know what to use or something, I'm just a beginner in java.

Comment: OK. So, which is the method of LabExer2 that asks the user to enter the name, the quantity and the price? (I know the answer. I want you to reason and find what you need to do)

Comment: @Groenhout that must be part of the problem (although he must have figured it out since the code is there, but commented out). If you read the question until the end, you'll see that another part, which is the one that he should figure out first (hence my question) is: *still not finished because I can't figure out the process in the other class.*

Comment: @JBNizet I commented it out because it is not correct and what I want is to input the two data separated only by a whitespace.

Comment: that's what your commented out code allows. Why do you think it doesn't? Have you tested it (hence my first question)?

Answer (score 0):

You can create two prompts, one to take in the `itemQuantity` int and another to take the `itemPrice` Double.

But if you want the user to input both values at once, you need to write a code in the readInput() method that will extract the `itemQuantity` value and the `itemPrice` value.

Try this:

```
public void readInput() {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the name of the item you are purchasing.");
    itemName = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the quantity and price separated by a space.");
    String userInput = s.nextLine(); //String to collect user input

    //code to loop through String in search for Whitespace
    for (int x=0; x<String.length(); x++) {
        if (userInput.charAt(x) == ' ') {
            //whitespace found, set itemQuantity to a substring 
            //from the first char in UserInput to the char before whitespace
            itemQuantity = Integer.parseInt(userInput.substring(0, x-1)); 
            //convert String to int
            itemPrice = Integer.parseInt(userInput.substring(x+1, userInput.length()));
            x = String.length();
        } else {
            itemQuantity = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
        }
    }
}
```

Pardon me if my code is not properly formatted, I'm new here.

Comment: Your main function can now contain:

`le.readInput();
le.setTotalCost();
le.getTotalCost();`

I think you can better simplify your code by using the class constructor to set the object fields.

Answer (score 0):

Only need to convert the string into Integer, and string into Double. Then, to put 2 numbers and separate them, use the one-dimensional array and the split function.

try this:

```
public void readInput(){
    //Enter the product of item name
    System.out.print("Enter the name of the item you are purchasing: ");
    ITEM_NAME = input.nextLine();
    //Enter the quantity and the price for the item
    System.out.print("Enter the quantity and price separated by a space: ");
    String userInput = input.nextLine();

    String[] inputArray = userInput.split(" ");
    ITEM_QUANTITY = Integer.parseInt(inputArray[0]);
    ITEM_PRICE = Double.parseDouble(inputArray[1]);
}
```